# Combine rows from two tables with different columns?

Tags: mysql, join, union

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this one. I believe it's happening because I am joining the two separate tables based on the same column (user_id), but I don't know how to fix it because the only thing in common between the two tables IS the `user_id` column.

Here is the query.

```
SELECT users_data_existing.`date`,`message`,`action`,`status`,`data`,
users_data_new.`date`,`data_new`
FROM users_data_existing
INNER JOIN users_data_action USING (action_id)
INNER JOIN users_data_status_user USING (status_user_id)
INNER JOIN `users` USING (user_id)
INNER JOIN users_data_new USING (user_id)
INNER JOIN data ON users_data_existing.`data_id` = data.`id`
WHERE users_data_existing.`user_id` = 2
ORDER BY users_data_existing.`date`,users_data_new.`date` DESC
```

The result, is that the `users_data_new.date` and `data_new` columns, are concatenated or "appended" to the previous rows.

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|   date   |  message  |   action  |   status  |    data   |   date   |  data_new |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|2011-01-01|    data   |    data   |    data   |    data   |2011-01-02| data_new  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2011-01-01|    data   |    data   |    data   |    data   |2011-01-03| data_new1 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               REPEATS PATTERN FOR TOTAL RECORDS IN users_data_new TABLE 

+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|   date   |  message  |   action  |   status  |    data   |   date   |  data_new |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|2011-01-01|   data1   |   data1   |   data1   |   data1   |2011-01-02| data_new  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2011-01-01|   data1   |   data1   |   data1   |   data1   |2011-01-03| data_new1 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But that's not what I need. How can I get the last two columns into a separate row? I think a `UNION` would resolve this but I can't do that because the tables are almost identical but don't share the `message` column.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected in the question, it was a `UNION` that I needed. The trick was to create an empty column in `users_data_new` to match `users_data_existing`. I also had a challenge with sorting it so I will include that here as well.

```
(SELECT data_existing.date AS submitdate,status_user.status,action.action,
data.data,data_existing.message
FROM users_data_existing AS data_existing
INNER JOIN users_requested_status_user status_user 
ON data_existing.status_user_id = status_user.status_user_id
INNER JOIN users_requested_action action 
ON data_existing.action_id = action.action_id
INNER JOIN websites data 
ON data_existing.data_id = data.id
ORDER BY data_existing.date DESC) //sorts sub-query

UNION ALL

(SELECT data_new.date AS submitdate,status_user.status,  
action.action,data_new.data_new,'' message //needed to add this last empty column
FROM users_data_new AS data_new
INNER JOIN users_requested_status_user status_user 
ON data_new.status_user_id = status_user.status_user_id
INNER JOIN users_requested_action action 
ON data_new.action_id = action.action_id
ORDER BY data_new.date DESC) //sorts sub-query
ORDER BY submitdate DESC"; //sorts the entire result
```

Keep in mind that with the alias for the date, the associative array key will be whatever alias name you use. i.e. `$result['submitdate']`